# Can't call $scope.submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to run a function `submit` but it just won't go. I think I might be missing something painfully obvious.

This is my code

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

var guestBook = angular.module('guestForm',[]);    

guestBook.controller('CouchController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

   // $scope.submit = 
    function submit (){
        debugger;
        console.log("Hello");
        $scope.entry ={};    
        var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        var url = 'https://sophia.iriscouch.com/guestbook/' +timestamp;
        console.log(url);
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'PUT',
            data: $scope.entry,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Authorization': auth_hash ("*******", "*******")}
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(headers);
            console.log(config);
        });
    }

    function auth_hash (username, password){
        var str = window.btoa(username + ":" + password);
        return 'Basic' + str; }
    }
]);

</script>


<div ng-app="guestForm">
<form ng-controller="CouchController" >
    <p> <input type="text" ng-model="entry"></p>
    <p><button onclick="submit()">Add</button></p>
</form></div>
```

I am trying to get the button to run the "submit" function. Would anyone have any ideas on how to get it working?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xHoi2Jgb3uLbIGWInI6Z?p=preview

Comment: what is the console error you are seeing ?

Comment: It wasn't seeing anything but I have found the issue. Thank you, Kalhano! It was because I had written function with a capital "F" somewhere else. :P Painfully obvious but it's one of those things that I had been staring at for hours and no getting anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ng-submit

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="CouchController">  
    <p> <input type="text" ng-model="entry"> </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add"/> </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Angular directive `ng-click="submit()"` instead of `onclick`.

Also, you've commented out `$scope.submit = ...`. The function should be attached to the `$scope` variable:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. :) I tried that and it still isn't going. The onclick was just a stab in the dark to see if it did anything.

Comment: Also tried. That comment out was meant to see if the "onClick" would work if I took out the scope. :(